# How to guarantee that a project has all references from the projects it references?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, dependency-management, copy-local

Consider a solution with many class library projects. Each of them has a bunch of NuGet packages installed, and there is a single unit tests project for each of these projects. Keeping in mind that the class library projects' references are configured to `Copy Local = false`, how can I make sure that the unit test project always has at least all references from the original project?

We've been bitten by this problem on a few occasions already. Out of nowhere, our nightly build fails due to missing dlls, and when we check what happened, it's usually that someone added a new package or reference to a project but did not install the same reference in the unit tests project. That problem tends to not manifest itself because in a dev machine, each project copies it's outputs to a separate folder. When building in TFS though, MSBuild is overridden and all outputs are placed on the same folder.

We are using the `Copy Local = false` strategy on everything that doesn't need to be directly executed (that is, only test projects and web applications are configured to copy local all references). This was done to avoid unnecessary copies of dlls and speed up the build process. By using `Copy Local = false`, we are required to explicitly add all references to each project, because they are not copied from referenced projects automatically. For unit test projects, this usually means that our `packages.config` file in the tests project contains all packages from the original project, plus test specific dlls like mocking frameworks and the like.

Personally, I like needing to specify all references explicitly, because it makes it easier for someone to see what is happening and what depends on what more clearly. We have had problems in the past with the default `Copy Local = true` too, so I'm not very fond in changing it back to that. But once in a while we stumble on a problem that relates back to someone not adding the required references.

Can I enforce this in some way, so that it would not be possible to *not* have all references from a dependent project in a given project? Ideally, I'd like for it to be a compilation error, but any kind of enforcement would be beneficial. It would be very cool if every project in a solution behaved like a NuGet package when referencing each other: with NuGet packages, you are always sure that all references are correct, because dependencies are explicitly stated in the nupkg and added to any project that adds the original package.

Comment: Not building the *exact* same way the devs build their projects is a Big Honking Huge Mistake.  You need to fix that.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not sure I follow you there. Are you suggesting that I either make the local developers machines build into a common folder or change the build machine to build to separate folders? If so, I'm not sure it is a big mistake like you said, because it is the absolute standard behavior in Visual Studio / TFS. If you are talking about something else, sorry for not grasping it. Could you elaborate?

Comment: It is pretty simple, just build the projects the exact same way the devs build them on their own machine.  When you do it differently, you are practically guaranteed to have build or unit-test breaks sooner or later.  The kind that the devs don't want to hear about and don't want to help you with because there isn't any way for them to reproduce the same problem.

Comment: @HansPassant The only way to catch that specific problem would be to configure the projects to build to a central folder locally too, but doing that would complicate the life of all developers hugely. You know, some of the projects are web applications. In the build machine, they are automatically "published" to a separate folder, "PublishedWebsites", which is what our deployment process picks up. In local machines this does not happen, and people need to be able to quickly run and test each site. That is why they are separated on their own folder.

Comment: @HansPassant I know you are one of the most respected C#/.Net guys in SO, so it surprised me that you suggested that approach. Perhaps you don't use TFS and use another build orchestrator? How would I have separate web sites locally if everything was in the same folder? Each site has it's own web.config file and required dlls. Making it a single folder locally is completely unfeasible now that I think about it. The fact that the build machine builds to a common folder was what detected the problem in the first place. Note that if it built as dev machines did, the problem would not be exposed.

Comment: @julealgon, notice that Hans Passant did not suggest you having single output folder on dev machine. His suggestion was to make both environments -- dev box and TFS -- follow the same build process. I'm 100% with Hans on this one. In your case you probably have to change build and deployment process on both dev box as well as on TFS.

Comment: @S.T. Yeah, I know where he is coming from, but there is only two options to make the process the same: either I change the dev environment to output to a single folder (pretty much impossible) or I change TFS build to output to separate folders (nonstandard and a lot harder to manage). But as I said, this is not the problem. The fact that the procedures are different just resulted in me finding the actual problem. It would still exist if I changed the build process, it would just be hidden, which is a _lot_ worse IMHO.